# Flutter Detects AVD But Can't Connect/Target it

Tags: flutter

I am new to programming never code before. Decided to start learning to code on my own and decided to start with Flutter since it can make apps in both Android and IOS. I followed the guide and set up an AVD. Under "Flutter Device Selection" it shows the drop down option of "Open Android Emulator: Pixel 3 XL API 28" and when I clicked it, an Android emulator of Pixel 3 XL would show up. However, Flutter is not connected to it; I can't test the app.

Answer (score 1):

After the emulator pops up, in successful scenario, you should select it one more time in devices drop down.
Otherwise, check the output of `adb devices` in console. Does your emulator show up in the list?

Comment: Would you mind to explain more about adb devices? I know nothing about coding. After the emulator pops up, the target device option still says "Open Android Emulator: Pixel 3 XL API 28". When I click it, it will say cannot open multiple emulators